# How do I check if all values in a column of a pandas dataframe are equal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe like this

```
  name data result 
0  x    100
1  x    100
2  x    100
3  x    100
4  x    100
5  y    100
6  y    90
7  y    90
8  y    100
9  y    85
```

I want to check whether each group in the `name` column have the same value in the `data` column.

So for each `x` group, if the corresponding `data` value are all equal, write `full` in the `result` column. If the values for a group not are all equal, write `nearly` in the `result` column.

I have tried grouping the dataframe:

```
dfx = df.groupby('name')
dfx = dfa.get_group('x')
```

but it doesn't really help in checking if each value is the same, write in the `result` column.

I have tried creating a function that will check for unique values

```
def check_identicals(row):
    if(df.sent.nunique() == 1):
        print('Full')
```

The idea here is to then apply that function to each row and write the output in the `result` column.

Ideal output:

```
   name data result 
0  x    100   full
1  x    100   full
2  x    100   full
3  x    100   full
4  x    100   full
5  y    100   nearly
6  y    90    nearly
7  y    90    nearly
8  y    100   nearly
9  y    85    nearly
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if all elements in a group are equal using pandas GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950883/check-if-all-elements-in-a-group-are-equal-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for compare all values in new `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df.groupby('name')['data'].transform('nunique') == 1,'full','nearly')
print (df)
  name  data  result
0    x   100    full
1    x   100    full
2    x   100    full
3    x   100    full
4    x   100    full
5    y   100  nearly
6    y    90  nearly
7    y    90  nearly
8    y   100  nearly
9    y    85  nearly
```

EDIT:

For test if all missing values per groups use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with another condition with compare mising values with `transform` and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
m1 = df.groupby('name')['data'].transform('nunique') == 1
m2 = df['data'].isna().groupby(df['name']).transform('all')

df['result'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['full', 'all_missing'],'nearly')
print (df)
  name   data       result
0    x  100.0         full
1    x  100.0         full
2    x  100.0         full
3    x  100.0         full
4    x  100.0         full
5    y  100.0       nearly
6    y   90.0       nearly
7    y   90.0       nearly
8    z    NaN  all_missing
9    z    NaN  all_missing
```

Comment: Is there a way to include a isnull() condition? Say if each data value for a distinct group is Null, indicate that in the result column?